# In Qmail, how do I redirect DSN / NDR / Bounce emails to another email address?

Tags: email-bounces

What I'm trying to do is:
I would like to redirect DSN/NDR/ Bounce emails to another email address.

I tried to do the following:

1. I have inserted the following line into the file:

   ```
   /var/vpopmail/domains/xyz.com/.qmail-default|/var/vpopmail/bin/vdelivermail '' /var/vpopmail/domains/xyz.com/rafael
   ```
2. To force a bounce message, I send an email to the "test@xyz.com" email account that does not exist.
3. I confirm that the email sent to the non-existent email address (`test@xyz.com`) is forwarded to `/var/vpopmail/domains/xyz.com/rafael/Maildir/new/`, but in the content of the message does not have the NDR (non delivery reports )

Could someone help me please?

Comment: I improved the list formatting and tried to merge the code in one instance. If it's not correct, please correct it with an edit to the question. The rest I just tried to improve.